# What is InputStreamReader really? and URL?

Tags: java, html, url, file-io, inputstream

My code works but I looked up a tutorial for how to read a web page and before i have lightly dabbled if File i/o but nothing like this. I don't really know whats going on with inputStreamReader and the URL identifier?
Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class urlReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL[] websites = new URL[4];

        URLConnection conn = null;
        // Try catch statement that handles no URL found and i/o exceptions //
        try {
            // a list of websites sorted into arrays // 
            websites[0] = new URL("https://www.pravdareport.com");
            websites[1] = new URL("https://pravda.ru");
            websites[2] = new URL("https://www.lefigaro.fr");
            websites[3] = new URL("https://www.independent.co.uk");
            
            // For each website it assigns the websites to webpage after each iteration of the entire loop //
            for (int i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
                URL webpage = websites[i];
                conn = webpage.openConnection(); // This is used so that for each website it ''opens'' the connection //
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF8"); // 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String lines = "";
                while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    
                        
                        if (lines.indexOf("<title>") != -1 && lines.indexOf("</title>") != -1) {
                            String title1 = lines.substring(lines.indexOf("<title>") + 7, lines.indexOf("</title>"));
                            System.out.println("The Title of pravdareport.com is: " + title1);
                            break;
                        }
                        

                
            }
            
            
                
                
            }
            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)? It says: *An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset.* What about that confuses you? Your Question is not really focused enough for posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you do not understand **character sets** (a set of numbers, each assigned to each letter of an alphabet, digit, etc.) and **character encoding** (how text is represented in bit & bytes/octets), then read this surprisingly entertaining article: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: It's hard to figure what kind of answer we can give that won't be too "jargon based". A URL is a way to locate a "resource". The `https` bit is the protocol used to communicate at the application layer (see OSI Model). The Java `URL` class encapsulates a URL and provides ways to open connections to the specified "resource". And `InputStreamReader` translates the "raw" byte stream into characters using a particular encoding (e.g., UTF-8).

Comment: Honestly, I think your best bet is to look up jargon/concepts you don't understand. If you don't understand jargon/concepts used to explain the previous jargon/concepts, then look up the new jargon/concepts. Continue doing this until you have enough foundational knowledge to understand what you were originally trying to. Note that doesn't mean you need to understand everything about how computers and networks work in full detail; only research what you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### URLConnection

A highly abstract thing - it represents a connection to a URL. It doesn't have to be active (in that there is a separate `.connect()` method, and things like `.getInputStream()` implicitly connect if it isn't already), and it can be to anything - a file, a resource in a jar, a BLOB in an SQL-based database, or a connection to a webserver, which is what is happening here.

Such connections can be two-way (where you can send data to them, as well as receive data from them) but doesn't have to be. Web connections are one-way, unless it's a POST call, such as when you submit a web form, where it's two way (you send the form data, which might be a lot if it includes a file upload element, and then you receive the response).

### InputStream

As produced by `con.getInputStream()`. An InputStream is a thing that can produce a stream of bytes. It may be endless (for example, a stream that produces random numbers, as many as you want, or a web connection, which could be endless if the server decides to serve bytes as long as you continue to ask for them), but more usually it will end. You don't know when - another property of inputstreams is that the source that provides these bytes doesn't have to tell you in advance if it will ever end or when that will happen.

`con.getInputStream()` represents the data that the server sends. It's *just* the data - the 'raw data' sent directly by a webserver includes headers and the like. `con.getInputStream()` represents **only** the 'payload' - for example, when connecting to `https://www.pravda.ru/` (if for some reason you want to do that), `con.getInputStream()` returns an `InputStream` that gives you the HTML.

### InputStreamReader

InputStream provides **bytes** and bytes are not characters. If you're receiving ASCII, there is virtually no difference between bytes and characters, but, it's 2023, and there are way more characters than that, so, for example, most websites are sent as UTF-8 where 1 to 4 bytes represents a character. `Reader` is to `InputStream` as 'character' is to 'byte' - where `InputStream` gives you bytes until the stream is done, a `Reader` gives you `char`s until it is done.

An `InputStreamReader` bridges them - it turns an inputstream into a reader, by giving it an `InputStream`, and a charset encoding. This code provides a non-standard way to say "it is UTF-8". `StandardCharsets.UTF8` is the standard way, `"UTF8"` is less standard (if you typo `UTF8`, you won't know until you run it, whereas if you typo `StandardCharsets.UTF8` you know as you type, because your editor will immediately red-wavy-underline it).

### BufferedReader

One 'issue' that connections can have is that they have peculiar chunking behaviour. For example, on just about any disk system (be it a spinning disk or a bunch of SSD cells) **cannot** give you single bytes. It can only give you fairly large chunks of them. This is a problem: If your code processes things one at a time, then an InputStream has to be allowed to be really wasteful (read an entire disk sector in, and then toss em all in the garbage except the one byte you asked for), because the alternative requires that the object allocate a bunch of RAM to store that stuff. Usually you'd want it to do that, but every so often you don't. Of course, if you 'wrap' that `InputStream` into a Reader with `InputStreamReader` you run into the same problem.

`BufferedReader` lets you opt into: Yes, please allocate memory for efficiency. a BufferedReader wraps around a Reader and doesn't change anything at all (it has the same methods - it is also a `Reader`), except its spec indicates that if you call `read()` (which returns a single character), under the hood BufferedReader actually grabs a whole boatload of them, gives you the first one, and stores the rest in an internal cache, and will continue to use that cache as you call `read()` until it has run dry in which case It'll ask the underlying InputStreamReader for a bunch more. Which will in turn call its underlying InputStream (which you got from `con.getInputStream()`) for a bunch of bytes.

### URL

A URL Is a "Universal Resource Locator". It's a spec for writing a structured line of text  that identifies a resource *and* how to load it. The web uses URLs - it's what you can type into a browser to tell it where to connect to and what to get from there. `https://www.independent.co.uk/europe` is a URL that represents:

- `https` - use the https protocol to connect to a server to fetch this resource.
- `www.independent.co.uk` - ask the DNS server (where is that? The system knows. Which it knows because when it connected to the network, the router in your closet or whatnot told it where it is) for the IP address that goes with `www.independent.co.uk`, then connect to that IP.
- `/europe` - and ask the server that answers there for this resource.

URLs don't *have* to describe web pages. `file:///foo/bar/baz` is a URL. So is `ftp://ftp.foobar.com/path/to/some/file`. So is `my-bank-app://whatever` which is how iPhones and android let websites open apps. It's a very flexible system. It's essentially `someprotocol://someserver/someresourceidentifier` where all those 3 things can be just about anything.

Comment: I wasn't sure that I could comment because I was suspended but i meant to thank you.